# Tests if ros master is not running using rostest

Tags: ros, rostest, rosmaster, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to write a test for a feature that detects if ros master is not running. Using `rostest`, which automatically starts ros master, is there a way to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225898/tests-if-ros-master-is-not-running-using-rostest/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've answered your own question: since `rostest` starts a master, you won't be able to use it for tests where a master isn't running.

Why not use a standard test framework such as gtest or nosetest for your tests which don't require a ROS master to be running?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-02-09**:
Looking at [a catkin's document](http://goo.gl/VTlshw), using non-ROS test structures sound like a right path.

> Nosetest is the framework for running Python unit tests. No ROS environment is available. See: Configuring rostest if your tests need a running roscore.